# How to Get Light Cover Off!

Tags: light-fixture, bathroom-fixtures, cover

I've tried turning, and the light cover is loose but no matter how much I turn it, it is not coming off. Any help/tips would be appreciated.[image]

Comment: Have you tried pulling it straight up while moving it back and forth? Many of those fixtures have spring clamps that hold the covers in place.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Please take our [tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

It likely has a spring / pressure / snap connector and is not a screw on type of fitting. We can tell that it's not a screw on since it's the same no matter how much or what direction you turn it. Try carefully prying it to one side or the other from the top of the light cover while holding the light base so to not put force on the connection of the fixture to the wall. More than likely it will just pop out. Don't be shy with the force, it might take a little, while of course being careful not to break or damage anything